# Copying latest three files from remote server

Tags: shell-script, rsync, head

There is a collection of .doc files, in addition to other types of files, on a remote server (which supports SCP).

I saw a script:

```
FILE=`ssh abc@xyz ls -ht /tmp/*.doc | head -n 1`
rsync -avz -e ssh abc@xyz:"$FILE" .
```

It can copy the latest file from remote server when it use the parameter "head -n 1". 
But I found it cannot copy latest three files from remote server even if it use the parameter "head -n 3".

Comment: first of all, don't use `FILE` as a variable. It's bash in built command.

Comment: OK. I will use `FILES`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `abc`'s login shell on `xyz` is `zsh`:

```
ssh abc@xyz 'cd /tmp && tar cf - ./*.doc(.LM-100om[1,3]) | gzip -3' |
  gunzip | tar xvf -
```

If it's not `zsh` (but `zsh` is installed):

```
ssh abc@xyz "cd /tmp && exec zsh -c 'tar cf - ./*.doc(.LM-100om[1,3]) | gzip -3'" |
  gunzip | tar xvf -
```

In any case, beware that `/tmp` (or any world-writable directory) is a mine-field. Above, we're careful enough to only select regular files smaller than 100 MiB (with `(.LM-100)`), and `tar` will not follow symlinks or read the content of devices or named pipes but there's still a race-condition where someone could enlarge a file to several tebibytes in between that glob being expanded and the `tar` command being run.

And of course, anybody could put malware with a `.doc` extension in `/tmp`, so you'd need to treat those download files very carefully.

It would be better to do that in private directory instead of `/tmp`.

Comment: If it's not `zsh` and `zsh` is not installed?

Comment: @WeiYu, then install it, you won't regret it.

Answer (score 0):

`ls` outputs 1 file name per line, `head` trims N lines but `rsync` expects a file or glob to process, you can do this:

```
FILES=`ssh acb@xyz 'ls -t /tmp/*.doc' | head -n 3 | tr '\n' ','`
rsync -avz -e ssh abc@xyz:"\{$FILES\}" .
```

Comment: I following your scripts to do it,but failed.
For example,$ echo $FILES get the  following  output:
/tmp/1.doc,/tmp/2.doc,/tmp/3.doc,

Comment: Fixed, I added the tmp dir on the rsync command but shouldn't, it should work now.

Comment: Please try running your script before posting it. 
I get the output: " rsync: change_dir "/root//{/tmp/1.doc,/tmp/2.doc,/tmp" failed: No such file or directory ".